# how to adjust a table in html

Tags: html, css

I'm having troubles adjusting my table from normal web sizes to mobile devices (it cuts in the middle)
I tried to fix that in many ways but all didn't work (tried white-space: nowrap, adjusting width, scaling it, max-width:).

```html
 <div class="contact">
                <h2>When to contact us?</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Monday-Friday</th>
                        <th>Saturday</th>
                        <th>Sunday</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%">8AM-4PM</td>
                        <td width="5%">10AM-2PM</td>
                        <td width="5%">10AM-1PM</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

```css
 .contact h2 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
  }
  .contact table {
    height: 10rem;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
  }
  td {
    max-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

[here is a screenshot of what it looks now]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNxpH.png

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one way to make a responsive table.
If it's not a very important component, I suggest adding tables in div and overflow on it to make a horizontal scrollbar.
You can find more information here:
[Accessible, Simple, Responsive Tables](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/)

Example:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_table_responsive

Comment: thanks! if there's no way to make a responsive table then that's the way! have a good day

Comment: There is always a way. You only need to look at it differently. You can create a component by using a div that resembles tables but physically it is not.

Comment: I'll keep working on that, thank you so much Kuci